# Segfault using a map with fstream

Tags: c++, maps

I am trying to read text from a file, and while doing so keeping track of the contents of the text. If a word that hasn't been seen before it is inserted into the map and initialized to 1. If it has been seen (exists within the map), then the value is simply incremented.

If I remove the action of calling the `[]` operator, then the reading of the file works fine. I output the contents of the first file into an output file for the sake of confirming that reading a file is a success.

*So, an issue occurs when adding keys/values to the map.* It seems that my code segfaults upon entering the while loop for the second time.

Here is a simple class which acts as the word counter, and a main method which handles the opening of the files, creation of an object, and the 
reading of the file.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class WordCounter
{
public:

    map<string, int> words;

    WordCounter operator[] (const std::string &s)
    {
        ++words[s]; 
              // If we put a breakpoint here in GDB, then we can print out the value of words with GDB.
              // We will see that we sucessfully entered the first string.
              // But, the next time we enter the while loop we crash.
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    WordCounter wc; 
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    string word;
    inFile.open("input.txt");
    outFile.open("output.txt");

    while(inFile>>word)
    {
        outFile << word << " ";
        wc[word]; // This line seems to cause a segfault 
    }

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

}
```

Comment: Your `operator[]` function can be shortened to simply `++words[s];`

Comment: As for possible cause of your problem, what do you declare that the `operator[]` function should return? What do you really return? *Should* the function really return something?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ah, so it should be a `void operator[]`? Also, thanks for the previous tip.

Comment: No, it should be something like `void add(const string&)`, it being `operator[]` makes no sense.

Comment: @PasserBy Could you elaborate on why it doesn't make sense? Is it because it is doing more than simply accessing the container?

Comment: `operator[]` looks like indexing into a container, using it as something else just misleads.

Comment: @PasserBy That's understood, but still doesn't give any insight to the segfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands right now, your code has a number of errors that prevent it from even compiling. After fixing those and adding a member function to see the statistics collected by the word counter, I'm getting results about as I'd expect (and no segfaults, or anything similar).

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class WordCounter
{
public:

    map<string, int> words;

    void operator[] (const std::string &s)
    {
        ++words[s]; 
    }

    void show() {
        for (auto const& p : words) {
            std::cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << "\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    WordCounter wc; 
    ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    string word;

    while(inFile>>word)
    {
        wc[word]; 
    }
    wc.show();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I see what. After comparing our code, I've come to the conclusion that returning a `WordCounter` within the `[]` override is what was causing the problem. Why, I'm unsure. Do you have any possible insight to this?

Comment: @FaridKaradsheh: Defining a function to return something, then failing to return anything can certainly cause a problem. In particular, the calling code can end up with an uninitialized thing that it then tries to destroy. Since it was never properly constructed, destroying it can lead to all sorts of problems.